# How to show value from dropdown menu in jsp page?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a dropdown menu and i want when selecting an item from menu just to show it below.
This is my jsp:

```
<body>
        <select name="courseSelect">
            <c:forEach  var="course" items="${courses}">         
                <option name="courseOption" value="${course.name}">${course.name}</option>   
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
             ${courseSelect} //for example to show it here
    </body>
```

And this is my servlet:

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    String courseSelect = request.getParameter("courseSelect");
    session.setAttribute("courseName", courseSelect);
    session.setAttribute("courses", Course.allCourses());
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

I tried to get parameters from select tag and also from option tag but it doesn't show anything. How can i solve this?

Comment: use `js` instead on change of select get the value and put that in some div.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript might be better to handle this case on front-end itself.you can change your code as below for Vanilla Javascript

```
    <body>
        <select id="selectBox" name="courseSelect" onchange="changeText()">
            <c:forEach  var="course" items="${courses}">         
                <option name="courseOption" value="${course.name}">${course.name}</option>   
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
             <p id="showValue"></p> //for example to show it here
    <script>
   function changeText(){
     var selectedValue = document.getElementById('selectBox').value;
     document.getElementById('showValue').innerText = selectedValue;
   }
</script>
    </body>
```